# AngularJS: How to unselect a span when selecting another

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a list of things that I display with `ngrepeat`that when they are clicked, produce an additional list of things pertaining to the element selected. My intent is to have the clicked element's background change color so as to show it selected. My issue is when I select another element, they both show as selected. Here is my code:

```
<div class="breakdownRow pointer" ng-class="{bSelection: selection}" ng-click="selection=true" ng-repeat="m in masterList">
    <span class="areaTag">{{m.area}}</span>
    <span class="storeNumTag" ng-repeat="v in m.valueList track by $index">{{v.toLocaleString()}} </span>
</div>
```

As noted before, the first click event works great. bSelection is my css class that has the changing of the background color. Again my issue is that once another element is clicked, the previous doesn't "unselect" per se.

**Question:** How do I un-give a class to an element when another element has been selected so that only one shows as highlighted at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set and check selection in concrete element:

```
<div class="breakdownRow pointer" ng-class="{bSelection: m.selection}" ng-click="m.selection=true" ng-repeat="m in masterList">
```

**UPDATE**

for selected just one - save not bool, but index selected element. `ng-repeat` create own scope, so on click *selection* created for each item. you can use *$parent* to create one selection in parent scope.

```
<div class="breakdownRow pointer" ng-class="{bSelection: $parent.selection==$index}" ng-click="$parent.selection=$index" ng-repeat="m in masterList">
```

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.masterList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
  });
```

```css
.breakdownRow {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.bSelection {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <div class="breakdownRow pointer" ng-class="{bSelection: $parent.selection==$index}" ng-click="$parent.selection=$index" ng-repeat="m in masterList">
    {{m}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works to select one line but doesn't de-select it when another is clicked

Comment: still not working for me. Do you have a plunker or jsfiddle example i can see?

Comment: @discodane, sure, wait a minute

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the help